# Replace characters at end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regular expressions to replace things at the start/end of all words in a file. Here are some example cases:

1. words ending in "ing" get changed to end in "gni": clear**ing** = clear**gni**
2. words starting with "sub" get changed to start with "bus": **sub**tract = **bus**tract

How can I isolate these words in a list and apply the example changes?
All words are lowercase.

Comment: Should "Subtract" change to "Bustract"?

Comment: Oh its all to be case insensitive, ill add that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\b` to make sure something is at the beginning or end of a word:

```
import re

sentence = "..."
converted = re.sub(r'ing\b', 'gni', re.sub(r'\bsub', 'bus', sentence))
```

Comment: What is the lowercase r at the start of the re.sub?

Comment: @Scherf: It means that it is a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

strings = ['clearing',
           'subtract']

for i, string in enumerate(strings):
    if re.match(pattern='.*ing$', string=string):
        strings[i] = re.sub(pattern='ing$', repl='gni', string=string)
    if re.match(pattern='^sub.*', string=string):
        strings[i] = re.sub(pattern='^sub', repl='bus', string=string)
print(strings)
```

Comment: Why do you introduce a match object?  Just do the substitution.

Comment: If the match is not there on the first iteration the 'ing' on clearing will be replaced with 'gni'. Then clearing will not match the second pattern, and sub returns the string it was passed so clearing is put back into the list. Run it to try it out.

Comment: In that case, change `strings[i] = ...` to `string = strings[i] = ...`

Comment: This works too though. I had not seen this before.

    re.sub(r'ing\b', 'gni', re.sub(r'\bsub', 'bus', sentence))